# Tomcat HTTP 500 Error for a URL

Tags: java, eclipse, http, tomcat

My API is running in Tomcat server. While trying to connect to a domain, i am getting HTTP 500 error response from Server. The same url works fine in the browser, also works fine if i run the class from eclipse.

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://<>
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)

Is there any setup needed in Tomcat end to make the HTTP URL work?

Comment: Whats the URL that you used ?

Comment: Domain is accessible?, means you could ping that domain? It shows that network is not working.

Comment: URL is the end point of a internal .NET webservice
I am able to ping that domain and also able to access from eclipse and browser. 
Issue happens only when i run my api from Tomcat

Comment: Please show your code and the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: Code snippet....
`OutputStream reqStream = con.getOutputStream();
      reqStream.write(soapEnv.toString().getBytes());
      reqStream.flush();
      
      final int status = con.getResponseCode();
      System.out.println("status:"+status);
               
      InputStream resStream = con.getInputStream(); `

Comment: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: <>
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)

Comment: at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1675)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1673)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1671)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1244)
 at com.ms.prov.cg.api.conn.HttpUrlConnection.requestConnection(Unknown Source)

Comment: [Edit] your question instead of posting code/stacktrace in comments.

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be on the network,since the server cannot find the source of the request.

- I would suggest you to try debugging the line of code where the exception is thrown.
- It seems that it works in localhost only. Try to check if your router is port forwarding is set.
- For tomcat make sure you have set it to listen on Wi-Fi or Ethernet port which is 80. It's maybe configured to listen only on localhost.

Comment: i am getting exception in this line

InputStream resStream = con.getInputStream();

Comment: Well, if your URL is "http://" then it's malformed... see that it's a proper  URL before trying to connect.